# Need to render a sidebar component onclick() from another component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, sidebar, eventhandler

I am new to react, I have a side bar component, which i am trying to render from inside another component on a button click, i have had some success but , the solution is not perfect, the side bar is opening on click but it is only doing it once, it is working again after i refresh the page

```
    //this is sidebar.js  
    class SideBar extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                sidebarOpen: true,
                sidebar: null
            };
            this.onSetSidebarOpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);
        }

        onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
            this.setState({ sidebarOpen: open });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Sidebar
                    sidebar={<b>Sidebar content</b>}
                    open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
                    onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
                    styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
                >
                </Sidebar>
            );
        }
    }
```

// this is how i am accessing it

```
  class EventCard extends React.Component{
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       //this.state = { isAboutVisible:null};
    }

    state = {
        isAboutVisible: false,
      }

    render(){
        const {title, type, description, icon } = this.props.event;
        return (
            <div ref={this.eventRef}>
                <span>{title}</span>
                <p>{type}</p>
                <img 
                alt={description}
                src={icon}
                />
                 <button onClick={() => this.setState({isAboutVisible: true})}>More Info</button>
                 { this.state.isAboutVisible ? <SideBar /> : <div></div> }
                <button>Delete</button>           
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EventCard;
```

// getting this error after i click on the button:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Sidebar`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Sidebar (at SideBar.js:19)
    in SideBar (at EventCard.js:21)
    in div (at EventCard.js:13)
    in EventCard (at EventList.js:7)
    in div (at EventList.js:11)
    in EventList (at App.js:19)
    in div (at App.js:17)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

Comment: What is `Sidebar`? Why you are rendering `Sidebar` component inside the `Sidebar` component?

Comment: Side bar is a side nav bar, i want it to show up when i click on more info button

Answer (score 0):

Your code if far from clear, having said that I think you need to do the following:

```
onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
        this.setState({ sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidebar),

You forgot to add `button` to `Sidebar`, you need to add `button` as `children` to `Sidebar` like,

```
<Sidebar
  sidebar={<b>Sidebar content</b>}
  open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
  onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
  styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
>
   <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>  //button as children
      Open sidebar
   </button>
</Sidebar>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ldqyr)